# How to call compare to objects within a class

Tags: class, object

I'm writing a class that reads wikipedia texts and compares how often the different characters occur within a .txt file.

For this I created a couple private instances

```
public class Frequencies {

private double[] characterInstance = new double[26];
private String input;
private String name;
private double numberOfCharacters;

public Frequencies(String string)
    {
        name = string;
    }
```

Furthermore, I have written a method that counts the characters in the .txt file and put them in the characterInstance array and method that calculates the frequency by dividing that element of characterInstance by the total amount of characters.

**My Question**
I now would like to write a method

```
    public double sameOrNot(Frequencies different)
    {

    }
```

that returns the absolute difference between the character frequencies of both objects of my class Frequencies. That is, if I initialize

```
Frequencies type1 = new Frequencies("type1") //And I give type1 some text to analyze
Frequencies type2 = new Frequencies("type2") //Also I give this some text to analyze
double result = type1.sameOrNot(type2)
```

How can I write the method sameOrNot in such a way that it understands to compare a new object type2 to the old object type1?

Comment: What do you mean with `the absolute difference between the character frequencies`? The sum of the difference of each individual character?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The sum of the difference in the frequency of each individual character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I didn't try, so I don't know if it works; I didn't even try to compile it).

```
public double sameOrNot(Frequencies other)
{
  // Initialize result
  double result = 0.0;

  // Loop over all characters
  int    counter;
  double this_freq;
  double other_freq;
  for (counter = 0; counter < characterInstance.length; counter++)
  {
    // Determine frequency of this character in both collections
    this_freq = this.characterInstance[counter] / this.numberOfCharacters;
    other_freq = other.characterInstance[counter] / other.numberOfCharacters;

    // Adjust final result
    result += Math.abs(this_freq - other_freq);

  } // for all characters

  // Done
  return (result);

} // sameOrNot
```

Comment: The thing I needed to use indeed was 'this', I didn't knew how to use it but have figured it out. Thanks anyways.